# Embeddable collapsible sections in asciidoctor

Tags: asciidoctor

If there is a possibility to embed collapsible sections in another collapsible section in asciidoctor?
I am trying to achieve something like (here Address is embedded in Customer):

[image: Embedded collapsible sections from swager]

I tried typing something like that (but unfortunately that doesn't work):

```
.first
[%collapsible]
====
First val

.second
[%collapsible]
====
Second val
====

====
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can nest blocks provided that the delimiter lines differ. When you use the same number of equals signs, Asciidoctor cannot tell that you are starting a new block instead of closing the first block.

Try this instead:

```
.first
[%collapsible]
====
First val

.second
[%collapsible]
=====
Second val
=====

====
```